# How to define ColumnHeader for a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml

I created following `DataTemplate` which used a `WrapGrid` as `ItemsPanel` for it's `GridView` now I would like to add `ColumnHeader` for each Column

My current XAML Code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <GridView Grid.Row="1"    
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"         
                ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyleIOhneHover}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"
                            HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch">
                </WrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Generates a View like this

[image]

But it should look like at the end

[image]

Comment: What should be in the header? Is it rather a group?

Comment: @Dani it could basically contain anything, but for the matter of testing, lets say each should contain his current the columnnumber as Text (0 ,1)

Comment: In that case I would probably create my own panel (instead of WrapGrid) and arrange the headers manually.